# Creating a Calendar Event with Start and End time in Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, calendar

I am working with a third party developer who is assisting me with developing an App for my business. We are using Parse as the backend service provider. One of my requirements for my App is I need to create a page to allow users to input an Event that includes a date as well as a start and end time. It is similar to creating an Event in Google Calendar where you can select a date from their calendar icon as well as start and end time. The developer I am working with was able to create the calendar, but said, "there was not a field to indicate the hours of the event. We require these fields on parse." Is this a limitation of Parse?

Comment: You want to have start and end time, right? Parse provides Datetime field which can store a time stamp.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. I need Parse to store a Start and End time along with the date of an event. I will share your response with my third party developer to see if it helps resolve their issue. Do you know if there is a link to documentation on Parse where I can direct them should they need more details?

Comment: I can see only this: [Data Types](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-data-types). I believe if start and end time stamps are present, we can easily calculate the day of the event and its duration.